# how should i get the shape node of imagePlane connected to camera in maya

Tags: python, maya

```
def connectedImgPlanes(self,dagNode):
    print "dagNode ",dagNode ,type(dagNode)
    sourceConnections = cmds.listConnections(dagNode, source = True) or []
    if len(sourceConnections) != 0:
       lc = sourceConnections[0].split("->")[1]
       atribVal=cmds.getAttr(lc+".imageName")
       return atribVal
    else:
        return ""
```

the above function works and returns the path with file name from the imageName attribute of shape node of imageplane, but if top camera has imageplane set then the above function doesnt work, in that case i get error saying *# Error: line 1: IndexError: file  line 1: list index out of range #* due to

```
newStr=str(sourceConnections[0]).split("->")[1]
```

and then I tried different way to get the shape node of the imageplanes and return an attribute from it,

```
    lc=""
    try:
        lc=cmds.listRelatives(cmds.listRelatives(dagNode)[0])[0]
    except TypeError:
           return ""
    print lc
    atribVal=cmds.getAttr(lc+".imageName")
    return atribVal
```

this one also works until we add the top camera and the code starts giving a different type of error saying *More than one object matches name: imagePlane1 #*

please some one help me out get the shape nodes of each camera and return empty string if camera has no imageplane set...

Comment: could you please refine and elaborate your question.

Comment: how to get shape node of each imageplane so that I can get its imageName attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an `imagePlanes`(dependNode) cannot have any `shape` node attached with therefore I am assuming it's the `imageName` attr of the `imagePlane` that you want.

The following function, if passed a `camera`, will return the `imageName` attribute of any `imagePlane` attached to it. And if a `transform` is passed will look for any `camera` connections to it and then return the `imageName` attribute of any `imagePlanes` attached to the camera that was found.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds 

def connectedImgPlanes(dagNode):
    # if we have camera transform then go to camera shape 
    if cmds.nodeType(dagNode) == 'transform':
        dagNode = cmds.listRelatives(dagNode, s=True, c=True)[0]
    if cmds.nodeType(dagNode) != 'camera': 
        cmds.error("%s is not a camera node" %dagNode)

    # get all the imageplane nodes connected to image plane
    sourceConnections = cmds.listConnections(dagNode + '.imagePlane', source = True, type = 'imagePlane') or []

    # collect all the 'imageName(s)' into a list and return it
    imageNames = []
    for lc in sourceConnections:
       atribVal=cmds.getAttr(lc+".imageName")
       imageNames.append(atribVal)
    return imageNames
```

Comment: I appreciate if you dont add one liners
I would try to put that in cmds version, since I do not want to import pymel.core just for this part of the code, and I am not sure if this piece of snippet would work with all version of pymel on different Maya ...

Comment: changed to *cmds*
And that code would have work with all future version of *pymel*.

Comment: I am glad you tested , about pymel i was more concerned with previous versions...

Comment: thanks a ton, the connectedImagePlanes receives shapeNode type, and in case the node is not found, it returns a run time error so I placed the code in try except block...and returned empty string...

Comment: sourceConnections  causes UnboundLocalError since the backShape doesnt exist in the beginning.. in that case I had to catch the exception using try ...

Comment: @user1176501 - regarding pymel... I know this is an old post, but all of the pythonized commands above started as mel, and still exist as mel. If you are worried about compatibility, use mel script instead. Code is simple enough that the python is not at all critical to what you are trying to do.